# Prevent MITM for an AWS RDS MySQL instance

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

What prevents anyone from sniffing (MITM) the traffic between an RDS MySQL instance (outside of a VPC) and a Web server if an SSL connection is not setup (default on AWS) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally nothing can prevent from MITM if both of these conditions are true:

1. There's no encryption.
2. The attacker can see the data i.e. has access to anything the unencrypted data goes through.

There are many [Scenarios for Accessing a DB Instance in a VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.Scenarios.html). I need to assume, based on your question, the worst case screnario: **both** DB Instance and EC2 Instance **Not in a VPC**:

[image]

While all the traffic might go inside Amazon's own (but public) network (which you could investigate with `traceroute`), this means that both of the conditions could be true. Therefore, you should either enable TLS or move your RDS in *Amazon Virtual Private Cloud* (VPC) – or even both.

This is inline with RDS documentation [Security in Amazon RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.html) (only the related list items cited):

> - Run your DB instance in an Amazon Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) for the greatest possible network access control. For more information
>   about creating a DB instance in a VPC, see [Using Amazon RDS with
>   Amazon Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.html).
> - Use Secure Socket Layer (SSL) connections with DB instances running the MySQL, Amazon Aurora, MariaDB, PostgreSQL, Oracle, or Microsoft
>   SQL Server database engines; for more information on using SSL with a
>   DB instance, see [Using SSL to Encrypt a Connection to a DB Instance.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html)

Even if you follow every step to increase security, you still need to trust in Amazon.